# Scraping website for prices using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I deleted the old post since it was not clear enough.

I am scraping a website using selenium, the issue I am facing is while scraping the field using

```
driver.get('****')
driver.find_element_by_id('fb_submit').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('')
driver.find_element_by_id('btn-login').click()
driver.get('****')
driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//[@class='price'])
```

is that this field first populates with retrieving till the data populate in the page. Hence it retrieve a list with ["retrieving" and not pricing]
How can I solve this scenario, I tried to use wait drive but it is already populated.\

```
                while tt:
                    elem =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//td[@data-title="Availability"]')
                    elem =[d.text for d in elem]
                    Availability = sele.xpath('.//td[@data-title="Availability"]/text()').extract()

                    # elemList =[d for d in elem]
                    for i in elem:

                        if "retreiving" not in i.lower() or "Retreiving" not in i or i != "Retreiving" :
                            tt = False
                            print(i,tt)
                        else:
                            tt =True
                            print("else" ,i, tt)
                    time.sleep(0.5)
```

UPDATE:

here is what I tried and still not working...

2nd Update:

```
   WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until_not(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.XPATH, ".//td[@data-title='Availability']"), "Retreiving"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If the element that will contain the price is identical to the element that says "retrieving" in everything but the text it contains (i.e. the element has just the `price` class before and after prices are fetched), you can write some logic to wait till the element contains the data you want?

Something like

```
while True:
    element_text = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//[@class='price']).text
    if "retreiving" not in element_text:
        break
    time.sleep(1)

# element_text might contain the prices at this point
print(element_text)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Will give it a try and make a comment tomorrow.

Comment: I have a question though, wouldnt this trigger an error cause element_text is a list? because I am retrieving list since it i find_elements not find_element.

Comment: ah yes you're right, then loop through each element and check the text of each? Hard for me to make the code exactly right without knowing what the HTML looks like, but sounds like you got it

Comment: still not working and I dont kno how on earth I update my code with what I did.

Comment: can you update code with enough code that other can replicate? i.e. the url you're scraping, and whatever other logic is necessary

Comment: First of all thank you so much for all your help. Second I Manage to solve it using while loop.